# Injectivity of theta function

Tags: complex-analysis, theta-functions

Let $\vartheta_{00}$ and $\vartheta_{01}$ be Jacobian theta functions (notations like on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function)). $$F:=\left\{ \tau \in \mathbb{C}: \mathrm{Im}(\tau)>0, \left| \mathrm{Re}(\tau)\right|<1, \left|\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{1}{\tau}\right)\right|\leq 1 \right\}.$$

[image]

**I need to prove that $$ k'(\tau):=\left(\frac{\vartheta_{01}(0,\tau)}{\vartheta_{00}(0,\tau)}\right)^2 $$ is injective on $F$.**

I tried to do so by looking at the theta functions' product expansions but did not succeed. Their power series did not help me either, but I am probably missing something!
How do you normally prove injectivity of a power series or an infinte product?

Suggestions are very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

write k' = N^2/D^2
you want to show that
f(t) = N(t)^2 - a D(t)^2 has one zero for any a.
Find equations relating f(t) on pairs of edges and integrate d(log f(t))/(2 pi i) around the edges of F.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to more clearly format your mathematics.

Comment: The review task came out with a 5-3 vote in favor of deletion. Not decisive enough for me to delete a post that has survived nearly 3 years. Apparently the users who voted in favor of deletion don't feel strongly about it, because there are no downvotes.